# Why is my voltage tester beeping only when the lights are off?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, switch

I am trying to figure out what's going on in the junction box from a bedroom in my home. A part of this involves using my tester to see if any wires/components react to having certain things turned on/off. Doing this, I've gotten a couple results that I can't manage to wrap my head around.

1. There's a wire in the junction box that the tester only beeps at when the lights are *off*.
2. The tester beeps at the lightswitch if it is turned off (which, to my understanding, is normal behaviour), but does not beep if the lightswitch is on, unless the tester is turned to the maximum sensitivity.

I don't understand what's going on here, or whether these two issues are even related. From what I understand the tester will beep at any live wire even if it isn't part of a closed circuit, but it seems like it's in fact more eager to beep *when* the wire isn't part of a closed circuit. What am I missing?

Extra information:

- The tester seems to work well otherwise, though it was the cheapest option at the hardware store.
- The lightswitch is a dimmer switch, particularly of the kind that makes LEDs flicker when dimmed. Dimming only very slightly changes the behaviour of the tester.
- This is in Spain.
- All measurements were taken in slippers, not touching anything other than the tester and the floor.
- The bedroom contains only lights (two, on a single dimmer switch) and a few outlets. From what I can tell, everything is on the same breaker and nothing is wired to ground.
- The following is a diagram of the junction box. The colors do not appear to be code.

[image]

- The following two diagrams are the wires that the tester beeps at when everything in the room is off, and those when only the lights are on, in that order. I'm not 100% on these diagrams, since the junction box is pretty cramped and I'm not eager to mess around with it while there are live wires inside. The wire referenced in (1) is the lower right blue wire (the one going into the yellow tube) - for that one I *am* sure that it beeps only when the lights are off.

[image]
[image]

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: It'd sure be helpful if you labeled some...stuff.

Comment: I assume you mean the diagrams. They're not labelled because I do not know for sure what any of the wires do. Apart from that, is it unclear e.g. what is a wire and such?

Comment: probably because it was wired by a monkey.  Wow.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Lexman Lx-M-101

Comment: @TigerGuy Yeah, from what I've seen the rest of the house's wiring is a mess too. Still, would be useful to know how it works.

Comment: That looks like a rebranded Klein, similar to https://www.kleintools.com/catalog/electrical-testers/non-contact-voltage-tester-pen-dual-range-12-1000v-ac-or-48-1000v-ac Which means maximum sensitivity isn't so much "more sensitive to the same thing" as "sensitive to a **lower voltage** range". That is useful in some cases but *not* here - signaling on 12V - 48V doesn't mean much, except phantom voltage, in this context.

Comment: Might be a good idea to get a multi meter and measure the voltages.  Spain should be ~220v between hot and neutral(and ground), neutral to ground ~0v.  The switch should have one always hot wire that should cause beeps if off or on.

Comment: my guess is that the switch is switching a neutral to light the lamp ... when off, one side of the switch is hot